# HTML file with <object> ".svg" file and angular binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, svg

I am trying to create an html file which has an object tag which embeds a ".svg " file in it. I would like to add angular binding to it. Suppose I have a circle in the svg file and the x-axis of circle changes with change in input of a textbox in HTML via angular js.My code is as follows:
I have tried with `<svg>` tag `<embed>` `<iframe>` `<ng-include>` etc now I need to do with obect tag and .svg file. Could anyone suggest a solution? Thanks in advance

```html
<!--Inside script tag:-->
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
tcApp.directive('clickMe', function()
{
return {
replace: true,
  template: '<object type="image/svg+xml" id = "myImg" data="myImg.svg" width="100" height="300" border="5"></object>',
        link: function($scope, element, iAttrs, controller){
element.bind('click', function(){
var ab = document.getElementById("myImg");
var SVGDoc = ab.getSVGDocument();
var SVGRoot = SVGDoc.documentElement;
var sibling = SVGRoot.firstChild.nextSibling;
var siblingItem = sibling.attributes.item(0);
var siblingItemNow = whoHow.nodeName;
sibling.attributes.item(0).nodeValue = "55"; //Here I want to set cx of circle as text input

})
}
});
```

```html
<body  ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div>
 <object type="image/svg+xml" data="myImg.svg" width="800" height="800" border="1" click-me></object>
 <br>
 Enter the cx here :<input type="text" ng-model="cx" ng-init="cx=20;">
 <br>
 Entered cx : {{cx}}
    </div>    
</body>
```

```html
<!--".svg" file contents-->
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<circle ng-attr-cx="{{cx}}" cy="40" r="40" stroke="blue" stroke-width="5" fill="green"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: angular is for HTML... you could just render the svg from a template like mustache and update the string if it changes, you don't have to code 100% of your app in angular, especially if that won't work; JS always works.

Comment: Could you please tell about "template like mustache " as I have no idea about it.. Is it so that the idea I prefer to implement won't work?